# MC-CDMA Spread Signal

Tags: digital-communications

In the MC-CDMA (to simplify with $1$ user), the spreading sequence is a sequence of -1 and 1. I would like to know if it is possible to replace this sequence with a signal $s(t)$ of bandwidth $B$ to do the spreading.

Comment: These are not mutually exclusive statements. The sequence that is toggling at +/- 1 with each occurance as a “chip” if rectangular pulses  will have a spectral occupancy as a Sinc function (Sinc squared in power) with the main lobe extending +/-1/T where T is the duration of each chip.  Is your question if you can replace the spreading signal with any arbitrary signal that has that same bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem to replace spreading signal with any arbitrary signal that has that same bandwidth. To limit the OFDM spectrum, you can add zeros on either side of the data before doing the IFFT.